# Bash extending completion on filepath

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I use Zsh predominantly, one of the features I really enjoy is path/filename completion.

The specific behavior I'm most interested in:

1. Completing a full filepath from partial matches, e.g.

   ```
   ~/w/m/src  (TAB)
   ```

   becomes

   ```
   ~/workspace/MyProject/src
   ```
2. Completion to a name at depth e.g.

   ```
   ~///src (TAB)
   ```

   Completion candidates are all matches of `src` three folders deep from home.

How can I configure Bash to complete filepath names like this?

(Btw: I know about autojump, this question is specifically for Bash completion configuration.)

Comment: You cannot, at least not easily. You would need to write a function that splits the path given so far into its component directories, find a suitable expansion for *each* in order, then put the pieces back together into a single suggestion.

Comment: Which, presumably, is what the zsh folks have already done. I'd love to find a way to do this in bash but given that there is already an excellent (and mostly sh-compatible) shell that does this already, I doubt you'll find an easy solution short of writing it yourself.

Comment: I had a feeling I would need to do this myself, but it might be fun.  Or I'll make do with fzf or autojump